# how to extract everything from a path using just strings 

Tags: c#, string, path, extract

I am given a path like this:

*string pathFolder = "**D:\\New folder\anotherFolder\folder\something.txt\**";*

and I have to extract every detail of this path using only string methods. Without any other library help.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: not clear on what you mean by "Without any Csharp help."

Comment: First thing that comes into mind would be `string.Split` but its C# as such ! !, so maybe javascript [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) ?

Comment: Presumably you mean without using the .net framework's Path class in System.IO, which suggests to me this is some sort of lame homework exercise.

Comment: I apologize for I wasn't clear enough.
By "Without any Csharp help" I ment ... without any other formats than string.format.

Comment: `string.Format` can't extract anything from a string. It can only be used to build up new strings. Please clarify what you can use. Do you mean that you can only use the methods defined on the `string` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `string.Split`:

```
var parts = pathFolder.Split(new [] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The better option is to use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class.